# Replacing contents of file in android sd card at an offset

Tags: android

How to replace the contents of a file in android sd card at the offset or with the same size         as that of the size of a file which already had contents

Answer (score 0):

with

you can also use `RandomAccessFile`

```
RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(yourfile, "rw");
raf.seek(theStartingPosition)
raf.write(...)
```

Comment: The offset in FileOutputStream.write is an offset in the byte array, not the file.  He definitely wants the RandomAccessFile.